# Android Studio(v 2.1.3) doesn't recognize strings.xml as resource file

Tags: android-studio, resource-files

Unfortunately, Android Studio's stopped recognize strings.xml file as resource file for all my projects. So now each string, which declares in strings.xml, in the source code emphasizes with red line.

Renaming of strings.xml file or reinstalling Android Studio fixes this problem, but I hope exist another solution.